# VBA - If a cell in column B is not blank the column A = 1

Tags: vba, excel

here is my case :

Column A is empty.
Column B is the room number of a guest
Column C is the Name of the guest in that room

I am trying to count how many room are occupied. so I put a count formula but the Result is 0. I don't know why..

Here is the code:

```
Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"
LRowA = [A4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

so then I was trying to put a formula to say if Column B as any Number (the room number), it will count as 1 in the column A. And then put a Sum at the end of Column A.

Here is the code that I am trying to put but it puts 123456 in the column C.

```
Sheets("Champagne").Select

For Each Cel In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
If Cel.Value <> "" Then Cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "123456"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Next

Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"
LRowA = [A4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

If you have an answer with the first code, I take it as well....

Comment: A simple worksheet `COUNTIF` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jeeped, Can you put it the code on the VBA with the count if..please.. as an answer....

Comment: If column A is empty and columns B & C may or may not be filled then there is no way to determine where to put the count in column A. Pick another column that is filled to the extent of the room data regardless of whether the room is filled or not. Supply sample data together with expected results. Are the room numbers **always** numbers or are some text (e.g. 101A)?

Comment: @Jeeped, No it is always Number. If there is someone in the room then the room number appear on the sheet. If there is nobody then the room does not even appear as a row the room number get erase completely from the sheet. what I want is to Count how many room are there in the Column C. let me edit my post and I show you on the excel file..

Comment: Re your first (and second?) code attempt: If, as you say, column A is empty, then `LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` will return the last row in the spreadsheet (e.g. 1048576).  On the next line your try to put a formula in a cell two rows below that last row, so that will crash.  Even if it didn't, a `SUM` of a lot of empty cells will be 0.

Comment: In your second code attempt, it looks like you are putting the number "123456" into column B, not column C.

Comment: @YowE3K, What I would like is to put "123456"into column A and I want to Count or From Column B or Column C. Can you modify the code to put the good caracteritics please.. I am a newbee lol I took this code from internet and try to apply it to mine.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count how many rooms (column B) are occupied I would use code like:

```
Function CountOccupiedRooms(sheetname As String) As Long
    Dim j As Long
    dim c As Range
    With Worksheets(sheetname)
        'Check that some data exists
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B2").Value) Then
            CountOccupiedRooms = 0
            Exit Function
        End If

        For Each c In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B2:B" & c.Row), c.Value) = 1 Then
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    CountOccupiedRooms = j
End Function
```

and then, assuming you wanted to put that number in a cell somewhere, that code could be called in your main code as

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C5").Value = CountOccupiedRooms("Champagne")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C6").Value = CountOccupiedRooms("ChocoStrawb")
```

The destination worksheet name ("Summary") and the locations ("C5" and "C6") were just made up for illustration purposes - you can use whatever you like.

Comment: it does not work. Look if I do it an another way, maybe it will be easier. Look answer just down.

Comment: I found the way to make it Work..... Thank you so much.. Now If I want to do the same but in an another Sheet lets say called "ChocoStrawb".. What should I put

Comment: @JohanEs If you wanted to do the same task for the sheet "ChocoStrawb" using my code, you would add another line to your main code along the lines of `Worksheets("Summary").Range("C6").Value = CountOccupiedRooms("ChocoStrawb")`.  That's the advantage of using small subroutines and functions - they can be reused with very little effort.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! I have ONE LAST question to be solved can you help me with that ?? the question is  "Recap of Number of word in a different Cell"... Please please Please....

Comment: Please, I have a problem, When There is Nothing in B2, It puts 1 in A2.. if there is nothing in the Column B,  I want to put 0 in A2