# Trouble Passing Object Variable within Functions VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that takes user input and places it in a sheet, based on job type. For the purposees of this we're only concerned with Sheet("Active Jobs").

I have a function which takes information from a UserForm, and places it into Cells, based on jobID. A simple count keeps track of the JobID, and places the job into the sheet, based on its ID, as such:

```
Public btn As Button
Public t As Range

Function GetActiveJob()

Dim i1 As Integer
i1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value '//Keeps count of jobs, gives the JobID

  With Worksheets("Active Jobs")
    .Range("A" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox1
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).Merge
    .Range("B" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox2  '//Handles a decent bit of text 
    .Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & (5 * i1))
    Set btn = Worksheets("Active Jobs").Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

  With btn
    .Name = "RemovetoArchive" & i1
    .Caption = "Archive"
    .OnAction = "RemovetoArchive"
  End With

  End With

UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = ""

i1 = i1 + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value = i1
MsgBox ("I1 = " & i1) 'For testing purposes

End Function
```

(The job ID needn't be unique)

As you can see, the userform creates a button with a name (Name of the function) followed by the jobID.

When a job is complete, & the archive button is pressed, I want to move it into a new sheet, called Archive.

To do this I take the string and manipulate it to get the ID Number, then convert the string to integer:

```
  Function RemovetoArchive()

    Dim ButtonID As Integer
    Dim ButtonString As String

    ButtonString = Mid(btn.Name, 16, 2)  '<-- Error here, (see below)
    ButtonID = CInt(ButtonString)

    Worksheets("Active Jobs").Range("A" & (5 * ButtonID) & ":R" & (3 + (5 * ButtonID))).Select


    MsgBox ("ButtonID is " & ButtonID) 'Testing
```

The ID Number is used as a variable to determine which range needs to be selected, and moved to archive.

Running this however, I get

```
Object variable or With Block Variable not set
```

I'm having issues with setting the btn.Name object. 
i.e.

```
I enter a job with JobID '5'
The information is created along with a button.
I press Button 5, a.k.a "RemovetoArchive5"
```

My code should take just the numeric character from the string "RemovetoArchive5" and convert it to integer, to be used as ButtonID.

As it is now, btn.Name, doesn't have the value

```
btn.Name = "RemovetoArchive5"
```

Will this have to be done in the GetActiveJobs Function? How can I pass the btn.Name Object, after Clicking the button it refers to?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The term "passing object variable to a function" typically implies *parameters*, and your functions have none. Did you read up on *parameters*? `btn` seems to be a module-level variable, aka "public field" or "global variable", which is the opposite of "passing parameters"

Comment: @SJR That provides me the same results as what I have now, through testing, and is perhaps more logical. I think the issue I'm having is that, when calling the "RemovetoArchive" Function, the btn.Name property isn't set, i.e. it has no value, and thus cannot manipulate the string.

Comment: If the error is run-time error 91, then it's not the `Name` property that has no value, it's the `btn` reference itself; `btn` is `Nothing`. Which type of module is `btn` declared in? A standard/procedural module? A worksheet/class module? A userform's code-behind? See [Variables and Scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2957/variables#t=201703081638244410797) in the VBA topics of Documentation.SO.

Comment: I deleted my comment because when I read @Mat'sMug's comment I realised I hadn't read your question properly. You need to address the issues he raises (though my suggestion should help in the end). Why does your function need to add the button and define its properties each time it's called?

Comment: Also, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module - I suspect `btn` is undeclared/inaccessible from the module you're trying to access it from.

Comment: It would be useful if your question indicated which modules each of your bits of code are in.  That would help us identify whether it is a scope issue.  But I think you have a more serious issue - assuming you are adding several buttons to `Worksheets("Active Jobs")`, when someone presses a button `btn` (once the scope is correct) will be referring to the one that you just added (and then only if it was added in the same session) - don't you want to identify **WHICH** button they pressed?

Comment: Does `Function GetActiveJob()` actually run without errors?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - It works for me. (Pasted that code into a module, created two sheets - Sheet1 and Active Jobs, set Sheet1!C4 to 5, made Active Jobs the active sheet, created a form with two input boxes and a button, called `GetActiveJob` from the button's Click event.)  It will have problems if Active Jobs isn't active though.

Comment: @YowE3K, I thought `Functions` couldn't generally manipulate objects.  They can get values from objects but not change them.  I know there is a quirky exception posted on SO but can't find it just now.  Only `Subs` can change objects.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - you're thinking of UDFs (User Defined Functions) which are able to be called from a cell in the Excel worksheet itself.  Coding-wise they are just like any other function but, as long as a function isn't used from a cell, it can do whatever it likes.  (Theoretically, the only difference between a Sub and a Function in VBA is that a Function is meant to return a value and a Sub can't.  But in this case the OP's function doesn't even return a value and therefore should really be called a Sub, but VBA doesn't really care.)

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - FWIW - [here's a recent answer of mine where I used a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42657717/6535336).  On looking back on it, although I intended it to be used as a "normal" function (i.e. a piece of code that returns a value) I now notice that it could also be used as a UDF (e.g. cell C5 could have the formula `=CountOccupiedRooms("Champagne")`) and it would **nearly** work - it would still need to be marked as `Volatile` in order to force it to recalculate whenever **any** change was made to a worksheet.

Comment: @YowE3K, I've learned something then!  I guess there could be some use for a `Private Function ChangeSomethingAndConfirm() As Boolean` in a module instead of having a Sub that modifies a Global `Success` variable.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - Yep - lots of code **calculates** something, rather than processing something - and calculations should be coded as Functions that return a value, and "processing" should be done as subroutines as Subs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the name of a temporary object that you created when you created the button can, at best, return you the name of the last one you created - and even that won't be possible once that temporary object is garbage-collected.

So, if you want to find the `Name` of the button that invoked `RemoveToArchive`, you should do something like the following, which uses the `Application.Caller` to determine which button was pressed:

```
Sub RemovetoArchive()  'Only use Function when you have a function,
                       'use Sub when you have a subroutine
    Dim ButtonID As Integer
    Dim ButtonString As String

    ButtonString = Mid(Application.Caller, 16, 2)
    ButtonID = CInt(ButtonString)

    Worksheets("Active Jobs").Range("A" & (5 * ButtonID) & ":R" & (3 + (5 * ButtonID))).Select

    MsgBox ("ButtonID is " & ButtonID) 'Testing

End Sub
```

---

A subsequent comment to the question by Mark Fitzgerald also made me see that there is a potential problem in your `GetActiveJob` code.  The section of your code which says:

```
With Worksheets("Active Jobs")
  .Range("A" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox1
  ActiveSheet.Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).Merge
  .Range("B" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox2  '//Handles a decent bit of text 
  .Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  Set t = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & (5 * i1))
  Set btn = Worksheets("Active Jobs").Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

  With btn
    .Name = "RemovetoArchive" & i1
    .Caption = "Archive"
    .OnAction = "RemovetoArchive"
  End With

End With
```

has a few references to `ActiveSheet`.  If the active sheet isn't the "Active Jobs" worksheet then that will cause problems.  (But it will obviously work if you always ensure that the active sheet **is** "Active Jobs".)  To avoid problems, I suggest you change that code to:

```
With Worksheets("Active Jobs")
  .Range("A" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox1
  .Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).Merge
  .Range("B" & (5 * i1)) = UserForm1.TextBox2  '//Handles a decent bit of text 
  .Range("B" & (5 * i1) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i1))).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  Set t = .Range("G" & (5 * i1))
  Set btn = .Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

  With btn
    .Name = "RemovetoArchive" & i1
    .Caption = "Archive"
    .OnAction = "RemovetoArchive"
  End With

End With
```

Comment: This solved it, and thank you for the additional information. The jobs get placed onto sheets determined by the value of one of three option buttons. So I was going to do something like:
   
    If optionbutton2.value = true then
      Sheet2.activate

for example, but your suggestion is definitely better imo. Thank you!